# Split string and calculate power of the 2 substrings

Tags: java, math, split

My input string looks like this `"10^-9"`. Since Java don't handle exponentiation and `"^"` stands for bitwise XOR, I tried to do it differently. I splitted the String in 10 and -9 and parsed it into double, then used `Math.pow()` to get the value of it. The code looks like this:

```
String[] relFactorA = vA.getValue().split("^"); //vA.getValue is a String like `"10^-9"` or any other number instead of 9.
Double pow1 = Double.parseDouble(relFactorA[0]);
Double pow2 = Double.parseDouble(relFactorA[1]);
Double relFactor = Math.pow(pow1, pow2);
System.out.println(relFactor);
```

But that approach results in an java.lang.NumberFormatException. In the code I cannot find an error, whether I did something wrong or the compiler recognizes the "-(Minus)" as a "-(hyphen)", but I dont think thats the reason, because both Strings look the same and the compiler should see this.

Comment: Use `double` instead of `Double`.

Comment: Does the NFE occur with both signs? If not, maybe run a String#replace() on it before parsing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably didn't split on `^` since `split` uses regex as parameter and in regex `^` has special meaning (its start of line). To make it literal use `"\\^"`.

Comment: thats it, thank you very much. Again something new learned :)

Comment: @Alika87 No problem. Next time use debugger or simply print data that cause exceptions. If you would print `relFactorA[0]` you would see that it contains `"10^-9"` so split didn't work as you planned :)

Answer (score 2):

`String.split()` uses a regex as parameter. If you want to split for the symbol `^` use `\\^` instead.

```
String[] relFactorA = vA.getValue().split("\\^");
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that [`String#split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) takes a *regex* and not a String:

> public String[] split(String **regex**)

You should escape the [special character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `^`:

`vA.getValue().split("\\^");`

Escaping a regex is usually done by `\`, but in Java, `\` is represented as `\\`.

Instead, you can use [`Pattern#quote`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29) that will treat the `^` as the **String** `^` and not the meta-character `^`:

> Returns a **literal pattern String** for the specified String.

`vA.getValue().split(Patter.quote("^"));`